# Ionic return filtered json array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

Im having a bit of an issue filtering the array to return all the values where the parent id is equals to the id that i send.

For example if i send and ID of 1 it should return a new array with 3 items, and ID of 4 will return 1 item and an ID of 5 will return one item but always in an array format.

Im more of a PHP programmer trying my hand at apps, any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
 .factory('Stories', function () {

    var stories = [{
        id: 1,
        parent_id: 1,
        name: 'Story 1',
        avail: 1
    }, {
        id: 2,
        parent_id: 1,
        name: 'Story 2',
        avail: 1

    }, {
        id: 3,
        parent_id: 1,
        name: 'Story 3',
        avail: 0

    }, {
        id: 4,
        parent_id: 4,
        name: 'Story 4',
        avail: 0

    }, {
        id: 5,
        parent_id: 5,
        name: 'Story 5',
        avail: 0
    }];

    return {
        all: function () {
            return stories;
        },
        getbyworld: function (storyId) {



            for (var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {


                if (stories[i].parent_id === parseInt(storyId)) {

                    //return new array here

                }



            }
            return null;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Cuz im not clearly understand ur question:)

```
getbyworld: function (storyId) {
      var temp = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {
           if (stories[i].parent_id === parseInt(storyId)) {
               temp.push(stories[i]);
           }
       }
       return temp;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted, thank you. I was so close but missed the count in the push.

Comment: ye i gave u all items :)  didint get what did u wanted  :d

Comment: Just wanted to filter the array by the parent id and return its items, above works perfect. Excepting answer now. Thanks again. :)